# no autopostbacks are working on asp.net page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, autopostback

I have an asp.net page that has some sort of data load problem.  I'm trying to find the bad data, but the result of the bad data is that no control on the page will autopostback.  Linkbuttons, Dropdown Lists, etc. on the page do absolutely nothing when clicked.  I was just wanting to know, does anyone know what would be wrong as far as javascript or html, on the page that could cause no controls to work anymore?  I even have a radtabbar from Telerik on the page and it does nothing when clicked as well.  If anyone has any ideas of what I should look for, I'd be very appreciative.  If I can maybe see what's wrong on the page, that would help me track down where the data is failing...

Thanks!

Comment: show us your code. Pure speculation without code.

Comment: @Matthew Cox that's kind of the problem... the code-behind is 2700 lines and the aspx is 2400 and I have no idea what part of the page is causing the issue.  I'm just interested in more general ideas of what could cause total asp.net failure on a page...

Comment: THERE WAS A STUPID VALIDATOR I DIDN'T SEE!  There was a blank field validator that was doing nothing but adding an 8pt asterisk next to a dropdown.  Thanks for the input and I've learned a valuable lesson here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing worse than 5000+ lines of code that could all be the culprit (as far as you are aware). I would examine all the javascript that is occurring in either the markup or code behind. It may be the case that there is javascript handling any form submits and cancelling them. This would cause no post backs to occur.

Also check if your code behind implements the interface `IPostBackHandler`. The method required by the interface is `RaisePostBackEvent(string args)`. There could be bugs in this method somehow swallowing post backs more or less.

Bottom line, lots and lots of possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for this.  This is in essence, what was happening because of a validator that output an almost invisible validation error indicator.

Comment: @Tyler aaa a rogue validator would definitely do it. I'll add that to my mental checklist for no postback scenarios. I bet that was fun to track down =P

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem with a rogue 'div' overlapping my controls without being visible and rendered them unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your @Page that  AutoEventWireup="true"